# Protractor hangs at "Selenium standalone server started "

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My team recently switched from starting the webdriver-manager manually, to specifying the selenium server in the conf.js file, as specified here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#standalone-selenium-server. I'm trying to run Protractor with the following conf.js, which takes a few arguments and then returns a configuration object:

```
//create-conf.js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const globalData = require('./globalData');

module.exports = (confLocation, specs, reportDirName, browserName = 'chrome') => {
  // We want the reports to be saved relative to the config, so we need to take
  // the confLocation as an argument
  const reportDestination = path.join(confLocation, '../reports', reportDirName);
  return {
    'framework': 'jasmine',
    'seleniumServerJar': '../../../node_modules/selenium-server-standalone/index.jar',
    'chromeDriver': '../../../node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver',
    'seleniumPort': '4444',
    'specs': specs,
    'restartBrowserBetweenTests': false,
    'capabilities': {
      browserName: browserName,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--window-size=800,800'],
        prefs: {
          downloads: {
            prompt_for_download: false,
            directory_upgrade: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    'params': globalData.browserParams,
    'onPrepare': function() {
      let Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: reportDestination,
          takeScreenshots: false,
          filePrefix: 'htmlReport',
        })
      );
      let JasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new JasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
          consolidateAll: true,
          savePath: reportDestination,
          filePrefix: 'xmlReport',
        })
      );
    },
    'jasmineNodeOpts': {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
    },
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, protractor is only giving a small amount of output and then hanging indefinitely:

```
$ protractor configs/reg-conf.js
[18:22:30] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[18:22:30] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[18:22:31] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.24.104.84:4444/wd/hub
```

The same configuration works on other co-workers machines, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of configuration issue I have. I'm on Windows 7, and it has worked on both another Windows 7 machine and several Macs. Because of this, I'm confident that the problem is in some sort of setup, not in the create-conf.js or reg-conf.js files.

Chromedriver version:

```
$ ./chromedriver.exe -v
ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f)
```

Protractor version:

```
$ protractor --version
Version 5.1.2
```

Additionally, if I convert the configuration file back to how it was before, and run webdriver-manager manually, protractor runs correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you restart then machine try it?

Comment: Yes I tried that, it didn’t help.

Comment: remove `seleniumServerJar ` and `chromeDriver` values from config object. protractor by default starts the selenium server by using selenium jar persent in node_modules.